# Use of StrLoc nested into a macro in uninstall mode

Tags: macros, nsis, uninstallation

I'm not an expert user of NSIS... while compiling a script I receive the following error:

```
!insertmacro: FUNCTION_STRING_StrLoc_Call
Call must be used with function names starting with "un." in the uninstall section.
```

While uninstall, the following function is called:

```
Function un.Uninstall
; some code

${un.GetMsOfficeVersion} $R0

; some code
FunctionEnd
```

In turn, the following peace of code is called too:

```
!macro GetMsOfficeVersion
; some code

StrCpy $R0 0
loop:
    ClearErrors
    EnumRegValue $R1 HKCU "Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Licensing\LastKnownC2RProductReleaseId" $R0
    IfErrors done
    IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
    ReadRegStr $R2 HKCU "Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Licensing\LastKnownC2RProductReleaseId" $R1
    ${StrLoc} $R1 "$R2" "365" ">"
        StrCmp $R1 "" +3 0          ;+3 if substring is not found
        StrCpy $R1 "16.0"
        Goto found
    ${StrLoc} $R1 "$R2" "2019" ">"
        StrCmp $R1 "" loop 0        ;loop if substring is not found
        StrCpy $R1 "16.0"
        Goto found
done:

; other code
!macroend

!macro _GetMsOfficeVersion Result
    ${CallArtificialFunction} GetMsOfficeVersion
    Pop "${Result}"
!macroend

; Insert function as an installer and uninstaller function.
!define GetMsOfficeVersion "!insertmacro _GetMsOfficeVersion"
!define un.GetMsOfficeVersion "!insertmacro _GetMsOfficeVersion"
```

I know that the issue is because of the call to `${StrLoc}` function. It should be different in install mode and uninstall mode respectively, that is `${StrLoc}` and `${un.StrLoc}` accordingly, but I don't know how to do it using this code structure

Any help would be very appreciated... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the `__UNINSTALL__` define to tell if you are in uninstaller code:

```
!include StrFunc.nsh
${StrLoc}
${UnStrLoc}


!macro testmacro
!ifdef __UNINSTALL__
!define /ReDef MyUn "un"
!else
!define /ReDef MyUn ""
!endif

StrCpy $R2 "3654321"
${${MyUn}StrLoc} $R1 "$R2" "365" ">"
DetailPrint $R1
!macroend

Section
!insertmacro testmacro
Goto +2
WriteUninstaller $Temp\Un.exe
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
!insertmacro testmacro
SectionEnd
```

This is not ideal, I'll see if I can get StrFunc to use CallArtificialFunction in the next release.